# No implicit Ordering Defined on Pattern Matched List

Tags: scala

On Scala 2.11.8:

```
 private def safeMax[A](xs: List[A])
                       (implicit ev: Ordering[A]): Option[A] = xs match {
    case ys@(_ :: _) => Some(ys.min)
    case Nil         => None
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:12: error: No implicit Ordering defined for ?A1.
           case ys@(_ :: _) => Some(ys.min)
                                       ^
```

Since `ys` has type `List[A]`, as I understand, then why does this compile-time error occur?

Note that I could fix it by replace `ys.min` with `xs.min`, but I'm still curious.

Comment: It also works if you write `ys.min(ev)`, `(ys: List[A]).min`, or `case Nil => None; case ys => Some(ys.min)`. This looks like an inference bug to me, but I can never tell. Might be worth reporting.

Comment: What is `ys` inferred to be?

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9879

Comment: I've added some (inconclusive) commentary to the JIRA ticket. Summary: it seems like a bug in the pattern matcher to me, especially since the code works in Scala 2.9.